# Prove that a concatenation of two vector series, one of which is linearly independent, is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Stuck on this proof for a custom concatenation operation:

let there be:
$\vec a$,$\vec b$ ∈ $F^n$, $\vec c$,$\vec d$ ∈ $F^m$, λ∈F

⊗ is a vector concatenation operator:

$\vec a$ ⊗ $\vec b$ ∈ $F^{n+m}$.  for example:

$$(2,0,3) ⊗ (1,2,3,4) = (2,0,3,1,2,3,4) $$

I have found that $λ(\vec a⊗\vec c) = (λ\vec a)⊗(λ\vec c)$

and : $(\vec a+\vec b)⊗(\vec c+\vec d) = (\vec a⊗\vec c) + (\vec b⊗\vec d)$

---

I need to prove that if {${\vec {a1},...,\vec {ak} }$} is linearly independent in $F^n$

and {${\vec {b1},...,\vec {bk} }$} is some vector set in in $F^m$

then {${\vec {a1} ⊗ \vec {b1} ,...,\vec {ak} ⊗ \vec {bk} }$} is linearly independent in $F^{n+m}$

---

i understand that if {${\vec {a1},...,\vec {ak} }$} is linearly independent then we pick scalars such that their sum is zero. then (${λ_1\vec {a1} ⊗ λ_1\vec {b1} +,...,+λ_k\vec {ak} ⊗ λ_k\vec {bk} }) = \vec 0  ⊗ $ (${λ_1\vec {b1}+,...,+λ_k\vec {bk}}$)

but that doesn't seem to prove anything..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the other way around:

Suppose $\lambda_1(a_1\otimes b_1)+\dots \lambda_k(a_k\otimes b_k) =0=0\otimes 0$.
Then conclude that $\lambda_1a_1+\dots +\lambda_ka_k=0$, hence each $\lambda_i =0$.

Comment: Then the question itself is wrong?

Comment: No, the question is correct, and this is a proof of that.

Comment: Oh, thanks then. I think if we change it to an inequality sign then it is a correct proof. Othe rise it's just reversing the if else statement which is not the questin.